# iOS NSDictionary accessing a JSON value

Tags: ios, json, nsdictionary

How do I access the value in "display_name", assuming this is an NSDictionary returned from a JSON get request?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
NSString *carName = vehicleListDict[@"response:display_name"]; 
NSString *carName = vehicleListDict[@"display_name"];

{
  "response": [
    {
      "color": null,
      "display_name": "hello",
      "id": 321,
      "option_codes": "MS01,RENA,TM00,DRLH,PF00,BT85,PBCW,RFPO,WT19,IBMB,IDPB,TR00,SU01,SC01,TP01,AU01,CH00,HP00,PA00,PS00,AD02,X020,X025,X001,X003,X007,X011,X013",
      "user_id": 123,
      "vehicle_id": 1234567890,
      "vin": "5YJSA1CN5CFP01657",
      "tokens": [
        "x",
        "x"
      ],
      "state": "online"
    }
  ],
  "count": 1
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? This post show no effort at all.

Comment: NSString *carName = vehicleListDict[@"response:display_name"];

NSString *carName = vehicleListDict[@"display_name"];

Comment: Include this in your post!

Comment: Read documentation before asking such questions. You'll never have any success if you are not even trying to search and read something. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary?language=objc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you response you can see that the `response` contains a array if item, so lets get the array:

```
NSArray *response = vehicleListDict[@"response"];
```

Then we can the value like:

```
NSString *displayName = nil;
if (response.count > 0) {
    NSDictionary *vehicle = response[0];
    displayName = vehicle[@"display_name"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *responseDictionary = json[@"response"][0]; 
NSString *displayName = responseDictionary[@"display_name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, the result is stored in a dictionary variable called dictResponseData

```
NSArray *arrResponse = [dictResponseData objectForKey:@"response"];

for (NSDictionary *dict in arrResponse) {

    //strDisplayName holds the value you want
    NSString *strDisplayName = [dict objectForKey:@"display_name"];
}
```